# Facebook app: can I invite a friend to a specific page on my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I'm making a testimonial app on facebook, so I want to allow an user to invite his or her friends to write testimonial specifically for him/her.

Thus I want to make an invitation to a specific page on my app, not just to the app. `mytestimonial.com/?user=sarah` for example, not just `mytestimonial.com/`.

Can I do it and how?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. Append a [`data` parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to your `apprequest` call. This can be retrieved when the invited user acts on the request IE: accepts it by clicking.
2. When an invite is sent to a user, store that `request_id` in your database referenced back to the user who initiated the request. Once the invited user arrives at your application, you'll check the `request_id` and match it back to a record in your database. This record can contain additional information that you can then use to redirect the user to the appropriate location within your application.